# saleor: react is not there in the latest release

Tags: saleor

The demo that exists online uses react for certain functionality, but when I downloaded and configured the latest release everything is static, is it not supposed to be latest version?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, in Saleor Summer release only Dashboard 2.0 preview(available at /dashboard/next/) is react-based. The rest of the website is still based on Django's static views.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sure a few months back I installed saleor and at least the filtering product bar (the bar located on the left) was working with react, if you go to demo right now, it is react based, you don't need to press any button to make your filters effective.

Comment: As far as I remember only demo branch got product filtering implemented in react, it still does, so you might want to check out the demo branch instead of the master

Comment: Thanks, when you said "as far as you remember" does it mean that you decided to choose a different commerce platform?